# Is cruel and unusual punishment allowable as a voluntarily-chosen alternative to a constitutional default sentence?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, constitutional-law, us-constitution, eighth-amendment

Is it constitutional for a person convicted of a crime to be offered a choice between two punishments, one of which would be cruel and unusual if it were the only option, if the other poses no constitutional issues?

Comment: Are we to assume that there are no legal problems with the other possible punishment?

Comment: I'd like so see an example of a legal punishment that a reasonable person would reject in favor of something "cruel and unusual," as that term is applied by the courts.

Comment: @bdb484 yes, that is to be assumed. I edited the question.

Comment: @EvilSnack I could see it happening in a capital punishment case. Suppose that a state decided to start using the guillotine for executions; there's a significant possibility that that would be considered cruel and unusual (https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/99312/would-the-guillotine-be-considered-cruel-and-unusual). Let's assume that it is. If a state changed death penalty laws so that prisoners to be executed are offered a choice between lethal injection and the guillotine, though, I don't think it would be entirely unreasonable for someone to choose the guillotine.

Comment: @EvilSnack - I would wager that a decent fraction of convicts would choose some form of corporal punishment over imprisonment.  Something like "10 lashes or 1 year in prison".

Comment: @EvilSnack https://www.npr.org/2022/04/16/1093193580/firing-squad-south-carolina

Comment: @JustinCave This suggests that a year in prison is more cruel than ten lashes.

Comment: @EvilSnack How about "What's the point of living if I'll spend the rest of my life in prison -- just put me before a firing squad now."

Comment: @EvilSnack - Not really.  It is very likely that courts would rule any sentence of 10 lashes cruel and unusual since it involves the deliberate infliction of pain.  It is very likely that courts would find no problem with a 1 year prison sentence unless it was grossly non-proportional to the crime.  But plenty of people would take the trade-off of short-term cruelty in order to get back to their life.

Answer (score -6):

### It's quite likely that forcing someone to choose between two punishments is itself "[cruel and unusual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cruel_and_unusual_punishment)"

The mere fact of forcing the choice is arguably "degrading to human dignity" and "patently unnecessary", which meets the criteria set in [Furman v. Georgia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furman_v._Georgia) 408 U.S. 238 (1972).

Comment: Nope, the rational is faulty.  Offered a choice between being skinned alive, (*cruel and unusual*) or being fined $25,  one would simply choose the $25 fine.  Choice, in and of itself, is neither inherently cruel, nor unusual.

Comment: Doubtful. The relevant cases are probably the consent to castration for shorter sentences cases. Freedom of religion abridging sentences often fail. But "cruel" sentences (already a very low standard) might not.

Comment: Is there something missing from this answer? How is "200$ fine or 20 hours of community service" cruel and unusual in itself because it is a choice?

Comment: "Degrading to humanity" is a very squishy standard, and I don't think you could find one knowledgeable observer who believes the current Supreme Court would apply it to a law permitting defendants to pick their sentence.

Comment: Even if this is true, couldn't the problem be avoided by defaulting to the non-cruel-and-unusual punishment if the defendant does not make a choice?